# New Excel.Application() kills debugger with no error

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I'm using VS 2008 and attempting to open an Excel 2003 template, input some values, and save the workbook.  I know that I have the right code for what I'm trying to do, but I'm getting some odd behavior when I call the New Excel.Application() method.  On this call, my app won't break, but the debugger quits with no error message.  The next line of code isn't executed, and I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on.  Any ideas?

Edit:
Here is the pertinent code:

```
imports exc = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
.....
sub createCSV(filename)
    dim thisExc as new exc.Application()   <------ Instant Death!
```

I've tried wrapping it in a try/catch, but that didn't work either...never got to the catch, just died on execution of that line.

Comment: What language are you working in?  You could wrap the call to the New Excel.Application in a try/catch and see if you are getting some kind of Exception.

Comment: I have one idea: Fix the problem in your code that's causing this to happen. What problem, and how do you fix it? Can't say - you didn't show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
Imports exc = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
Public Sub openExcelFile()
    Dim thisExec As exc.Application

    thisExec = New exc.Application

    thisExec.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    openExcelFile()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I implemented this change and it still crashes just the same way on the line 'thisExec = New exc.Application'

Comment: Did you add a reference to the excel library?   The code supplied has been tested and does work so there is something else that is afoot.

Comment: It's referenced.  I've removed and re-added the reference with no effect.

Comment: I ended up using a workaround for this issue.  A streamwriter into a .csv file works in this instance.